# How do I download the entire pypi Python Package Index

Tags: python, pypi

I'm trying to find a way to download the entire PyPi index - and only the index - no code files. I'm wanting to analyze license types to be able to rule out libraries that have too restrictive license types. I've looked online and through the user's guide, but if the answer is there, it eludes me.

Comment: You can use the [JSON interface](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyPIJSON?action=show&redirect=PyPiJson) to get information about a given package name.

The [master list of package names exists here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/?).

Comment: Morgan - thanks. That list give the name and description, but I'm looking for the full data - license type, tags, author, etc.

Comment: Yup, that's the first link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you can use [PyPi's Simple Index](https://pypi.python.org/simple) to get a simple list of packages without overhead. And then send a GET request to

```
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/<package-name>/json
```

This will return a JSON response containing all the metadata information regarding the package (including the license).

Comment: But the API is heavily rate limited and would take ages to iterate over all the packages.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the dataset [bigquery-public-data.pypi](https://console.cloud.google.com/search;q=bigquery-public-data:pypi) in google cloud

for example

```sql
-- preview some licenses
SELECT substring(t.license, 0, 100) as license_start
FROM `bigquery-public-data.pypi.distribution_metadata` as t
group by t.license
order by length(t.license)
LIMIT 1000
OFFSET 0

-- get pypi packages with permissive licenses
SELECT t.name as package_name,
  substring(t.license, 0, 50) as license_start
FROM `bigquery-public-data.pypi.distribution_metadata` as t
where t.license like '%MIT%'
  or t.license like '%BSD%'
  or t.license like '%ISC%'
  or t.license like '%public domain%'
  or t.license like '%cc0%'
  or t.license like '%cc-0%'
  or t.license like '%unlicense%'
LIMIT 100000
OFFSET 0
```

off topic:

select popular python packages, ranked by downloads per month

```sql
-- get popular versions of pypi packages
SELECT count(*) as dl_per_month, t.project, t.file.version
FROM `bigquery-public-data.pypi.file_downloads` as t
WHERE "2022-02-01" <= DATE(timestamp)
  and DATE(timestamp) < "2022-03-01"
group by t.project, t.file.version
order by dl_per_month desc
LIMIT 150000
OFFSET 0
```

related: partial scrapes of pypi are used in [mach-nix](https://github.com/DavHau/mach-nix)

- [nix-pypi-fetcher](https://github.com/DavHau/nix-pypi-fetcher) has filenames and checksums
- [pypi-deps-db](https://github.com/DavHau/pypi-deps-db) has dependencies