# Get huge number of python packages

Tags: python, pypi

I'm currently trying to do some "large-scale" analysis of python packages and therefore I need a lot of python packages.

Is there any possibility to get a large number of python packages (be it as .whl, .zip, ...) in a somehow automated way e.g., download the top 10000 packages from pypi?

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39537938/how-do-i-download-the-entire-pypi-python-package-index

Comment: This is very nearly a duplicate of the question that @jfleach linked. If something about that doesn't answer your question, then could you edit your question to distinguish it?

Comment: Ok thats embarassing - it is a duplicate of the question @jfleach linked to. I did search stackoverflow but somehow missed this question.